# Set selected drop down and then get value on "$_GET['user_level']" PHP

Tags: php, select, get

I have a dropdown on my site which is static, but the value is different for each user. I'm wanting to have it so that it has a selected value based on the user level, but if I change my selection and press save it will update that value in the table. However every time It's just setting the value to 0.

Select code so far:

```
<select id="user_level<?php echo $rrows['id']; ?>" name="user_level<?php echo $rlurows['id']; ?>">
    <option value="5"<?php if($rlurows['user_level'] == 5){ echo " selected=\"selected\"";} ?>>Admin</option>
    <option value="4"<?php if($rlurows['user_level'] == 4){ echo " selected=\"selected\"";} ?>>Staff</option>
    <option value="3"<?php if($rlurows['user_level'] == 3){ echo " selected=\"selected\"";} ?>>Lead</option>
    <option value="2"<?php if($rlurows['user_level'] == 2){ echo " selected=\"selected\"";} ?>>Guard</option>
    <option value="1"<?php if($rlurows['user_level'] == 1){ echo " selected=\"selected\"";} ?>>Camp</option>
    <option value="0"<?php if($rlurows['user_level'] == 0){ echo " selected=\"selected\"";} ?>>Guest</option>
</select>
```

On Save Code:

```
onclick='$.get("do.php",{ cmd: "edit", user_level:$("input#user_level<?php echo $rlurows['id']; ?>").val(),id: "<?php echo $rlurows['id']; ?>" } ,function(data){ $("#msg<?php echo $rlurows['id']; ?>").html(data); });'
```

Code retrieving in do.php:

```
$lvl = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['user_level']);
```

Can anyone see the issue that is making my code not work? Do I need to post any more code?

**EDIT:**

Whoops. Must be tired. :). `<select id="user_level<?php echo $rrows['id']; ?>` should be `<select id="user_level<?php echo $rlurows['id']; ?>` and `input#user_level` should be `select#user_level`

Comment: Whoops. Must be tired. :). `<select id="user_level<?php echo $rrows['id']; ?>"` should be `<select id="user_level<?php echo $rlurows['id']; ?>"` and `input#user_level` should be `select#user_level`

Comment: just edit your question, don't put it in the comments

Comment: Are you echoing the JS code through php, or is it in a js file?

Comment: are you echoing this code via php? onclick='$.get("do.php",{ cmd: "edit", user_level:$("input#user_level<?php echo $rlurows['id']; ?>").val(),id: "<?php echo $rlurows['id']; ?>" } ,function(data){ $("#msg<?php echo $rlurows['id']; ?>").html(data); });'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<select id="user_level<?php echo $rrows['id']; ?>` should be `<select id="user_level<?php echo $rlurows['id']; ?>` and `input#user_level` should be `select#user_level`